# ASP URLDecode - Incorrect Conversion

Tags: asp-classic

I have a website where google pics up some links on my site and sends throught the following URL

http://www.globalpropertyonline.net/test.asp?town=gand%EDa

I have one of the URLDecode Functions I found on the net to Decode the %ED

However, this seems not to be working the correct way.

The %ED should be this : í

So when I Decode it the word should be gandía

But instead I get the following word : gandï¿½a

On the page where google gets the link, it is displayed correctly as gandía but it prompts me in webmaster tools that the following link has a error 500 and this is because when I try to take this name and sends it to the MYSQL query it crash with error 500 but if I would have had gandía then it worked !

So, my main problem is that I am getting the %ED sent as URLEncode as it seems and I want to Decode it before I send it to my database query.

In my ASP Page I am using UTF-8 Encodeing as follows.

```
<%@ CodePage=65001 Language="VBScript"%> 
<%
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "utf-8"
```

This is the Code I am using to Decode it but instead if getting the gandía I get this : gandï¿½a

any help will be much apreciated

```
<%@ CodePage=65001 Language="VBScript"%> 
<%
Response.CodePage = 65001
Response.CharSet = "utf-8" 

MyTown = Request("town")

response.write URLDecode(MyTown)


    Function URLDecode(str) 
        str = Replace(str, "+", " ") 
        For i = 1 To Len(str) 
            sT = Mid(str, i, 1) 
            If sT = "%" Then 
                If i+2 < Len(str) Then 
                    sR = sR & _ 
                        Chr(CLng("&H" & Mid(str, i+1, 2))) 
                    i = i+2 
                End If 
            Else 
                sR = sR & sT 
            End If 
        Next 
        URLDecode = sR 
    End Function

%>
```

Comment: Have you tried character ascii code?

Comment: Hi, No. how would I use it ? Instead of the URLDecode ? |Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not defined the page as UTF-8 *client-side*. You can this by adding this inside `<head></head>`:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: Thansk. I have added it and it makes no difference.

Comment: Hi. I have removed the URLDECODE and now the result is with a squerblock. Check here : I have created test2.asp to show this. - http://www.globalpropertyonline.net/test2.asp?town=gand%EDa

Comment: The %ED in your url is not valid UTF-8 for í. This works: [link](http://www.globalpropertyonline.net/test2.asp?town=gand%C3%ADa)

Comment: So, now I am confused. Why would Google then pick it up as %ED and not %C3%AD ? if for example, you look on the webpage you see the link and it shows the í correct on the browser, but in google webmaster tools it sais from this page there is a link and then shows the link with the %ED in it and that then fails.

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe these are old cached results?

Comment: I hope so, I have set them as fixed on the webmaster tools and hopefully they will not come back. Thanks for your help !